# Wordpress php quiz - code returns values of quiz regardless of user. How do i make it only returns current users values?

Tags: php, wordpress

I’ve got a quiz that users fill out on wordpress using the plugin FSQM Pro and when they submit it they are redirected to a page that will display some text along with their answer to a question in the quiz. To recall the answer they submit, I have used this code:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;
    $form_id = 9;
    $data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']} WHERE form_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1", $form_id ) );
    foreach ( $data_ids as $data_id ) {
        $data = new IPT_FSQM_Form_Elements_Data( $data_id );
        echo wpautop( $data->data->pinfo[14]['value'] );
    }
?>
```

However when I execute it, it returns the most recent value regardless of user. How would I get it to only return the most recent value of the current user?

#### ----------Update----------

After a lot of tinkering it is now working. The correct code is as follows

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info, $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $form_id = 9;
    $data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id 
        FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']}   
        WHERE form_id = %d   
        AND user_id = %d   
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1", $form_id, $user_ID ) );

    foreach ( $data_ids as $data_id ) {
    $data = new IPT_FSQM_Form_Elements_Data( $data_id );
    echo wpautop( $data->data->pinfo[14]['value'] );
}
?>
```

Massive thank you's to everyone that gave their time to helping me with this.

Comment: Is the user in the same row as the id and the form_id?

Comment: Im not really sure, I have very little experience working with databases. How would I find out?

Comment: Depending on your hosting, access your sql databases (probably through phpmyadmin) and click the table you want. Which you can figure out the name by running this: `echo $ipt_fsqm_info['data_table'];` underneath your script above.

Comment: Okay i managed to do that and it shows this table http://tinypic.com/r/25088c5/8 Sorry for the hassle here, I really appreciate your time helping me.

Comment: See the column that says user_id? Thats what you want. Do you by any chance know if the user that is doing the quiz has their user id stored in a session variable? If so then I can solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way your table is setup you can have it read only the quiz that is associated with the user by adding `AND user_id = %d", $form_id, $user_id ) );` You just need to make sure that `$user_id` is set to the id of the user currently logged in which will probably be in a session (or however it knows what user to select).

For example:

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
```

The new code

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info;

    $userid = $_SESSION['userid']; //Change

    $form_id = 9;
    $data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']} WHERE form_id = %d AND user_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1", $form_id, $user_id ) );
    foreach ( $data_ids as $data_id ) {
        $data = new IPT_FSQM_Form_Elements_Data( $data_id );
        echo wpautop( $data->data->pinfo[14]['value'] );
    }
?>
```

Comment: That was sort of how I imagined it to be. Unfortunately it isn't outputting anything anymore. As I am using wordpress, would it be $userid = get_current_user_id(); ?

Comment: That could possibly be it. Unfortunately I would not be able to help you find that because I don't have all your code. But you could first test it by looking in your database, taking any user_id value and setting $user_id = to that number. If it works then you can start testing with variables.

Comment: I just tried setting `$user_id = 1;` and it didn't work. I also tried changing the code to 
`global $wpdb, $ipt_fsqm_info, $user_ID;
get_currentuserinfo();
$form_id = 9;
$data_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id FROM {$ipt_fsqm_info['data_table']} WHERE form_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1 AND user_id = %d", $form_id, $user_ID ) );`....... that didnt work either though :/ However, I think that may be on the correct path as I came across this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: I apologize. I had the `AND user_id=` out of place :/ try my edited answer.